# how to make xml with android:digits and android:imeOptions="actionDone" work properly in Android

Tags: android, xml

I have this xml editText

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_alr_last_name_m"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
    android:hint="@string/last_name_m"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:maxLength="20"
    android:maxLines="1"/>
```

And it works well, the done button appears to hide the keyboard and finish the input session.

[image]

But, when I want it to restrict just to alpha charaters by adding **android:digits** like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_alr_last_name_m"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
    android:hint="@string/last_name_m"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    android:maxLength="20"
    android:maxLines="1"/>
```

then, actionDone button changes to simply enter button:

[image]

and when I touch it, nothing happens, keyboard doesn't hide, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

try to

add

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

or

add
 `android:singleLine="true"`instead `android:maxLines="1"` of  to your edit text tag and it should work 
then the Done/Enter key should now moves the focus when a `android:digits` is restricting the characters entered

or

```
editTextView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

Comment: android:singleLine="true" is deprecated, I use android:maxLines="1" instead, I did what you suggested but android:imeOptions="actionNext" doesn't hide keyboard neither when I touch Enter key

Comment: I had the same problem and I tried all sorts of different combinations but the only thing that worked was using the deprecated singleLine="true"